# How to add list from text file to embed?

Tags: embedding, discord.py

Hi I'm trying to embed some content from a .txt file as a list in to an embed however I'm having an issue to display it as a list on the command !changelog .

I get this error:

`raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: BAD REQUEST (status code: 400): Invalid Form Body`

Here is what I have got so far:

```
@commands.command(invoke_without_command=True, case_insensitive=True)
@checks.is_channel_mod()
async def changelog(self, ctx):


    changelog = open("changelog.txt").readlines()

    embed = discord.Embed(description=changelog, colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF)))
    embed.title = "Changelog"
    embed.set_image(url='')
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join the list with newlines:

```
embed = discord.Embed(description='\n'.join(changelog), 
                      colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF))
                      title='Changelog')
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

or just use `read` instead of `readlines`

```
with open("changelog.txt") as f:
    changelog = f.read()

embed = discord.Embed(description=changelog, 
                      colour=discord.Color(random.randint(0x000000, 0xFFFFFF))
                      title='Changelog')
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Je vous remercie